# PHP Return strategy. One single type or more?

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture, return-type

I've build big php applications but i am know asking myself the question: Should a function return only one data type and null OR is it ok to return more data types. Because it somehow now started to feel dirty to retun more then one datatype (except null) because it invites you to write things like this after a function call:

```
if(is_array($returnVariable)) { 
    // do something
} else if(is_int($returnVarable)) { 
    // do something else
}
```

It seems more logically to return only one thing from a function or nothing at all because you don't have to litter code with if's and elses everywhere. But i may be completely off. Take for example this function:

```
public function update(array $data, Model $user)
{
    if(!is_a($user, User::class)) return null;

    //Update the user
    $user->fill($data);

    //Send the user an activated notification if it was activated and it was not earlier.
    if($user->getOriginal('activated') == 0 && $user->activated == 1) {
        $user->activated_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        $user->notify(new ActivatedUserNotification($user));
    }

    $saved = $user->save();

    //User was not updated because of an error
    if(!$saved) return null;

    //User was successfully updated. Return the user
    return $user;
}
```

I actually would like to return one thing or null. And i do so. But since i return multiple nulls i cannot get specific info why it returned null at the place i call that function. Or may this be an indication that the function violates something like the seperation of concerns principle? I also have other cases like this where so please don't be too specific in solving this specific function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes a lot of sense to return only one type and throw an exception if that type cannot be returned in some cases. In others, it makes more sense to return `null` or that type.

If you're using PHP 7 you can [declare a return type](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) like this...

```
function sum($a, $b): float {
    return $a + $b;
}
```

This can help you make sure your function is not doing too much and make it easier to consumer your class'API.

It does have limits though. There is no [co/contra variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in PHP (yet) so there are situations (like an interface) which type hints will actually hinder the simplicity of your API.Additionally there are cases where you might want to use a [generic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) as a return type. These are also not a part of PHP yet, so in cases where you'd want to use a generic as a type hint, you'll have to live without that type hint for now.

You seem to have noticed some of the benefits of using a return type already, as well as the benefits of using a parameter type.

The use of typing parameters is quite apparent: it reduces the complexity of the function and makes it lean towards doing one concise thing.

In my mind, using a return type does the same thing...but instead of reducing the complexity inside your method, it reduces the complexity of the code that executes that method...which is arguably more important because the complex code which calls the method will need to handle the variable return types all over the place.

Simple example...

```
function add($a, $b) {
  if (is_string($a) && is_string($b)) {
    return $a . $b;
  } else if (is_int($a) && is_int($b)) {
    return $a + $b;
  }
}
```

This function does not type its parameters, so we need to think about its common use cases and handle the different parameter types in the function. It makes our function lack focus, and we'll never discover all the possible cases, meaning the function will likely break and then increase in scope.

We also don't know what the return type will be, so everywhere that function is consumed we need to think about that...

```
$result = add($a, $b);
if (is_string($result)) {
  // Do something
} else if (is_int($result)) {
  // Do something else
}
```

We can fix that:

```
function add(Int $a, Int $b) : Int {
    return $a + $b;
}
function concatStrings(String $a, String $b) : String {
    return $a . $b;
}
```

Now wherever we use these functions our type checking logic disappears. Our functions are shorter and less complicated, and everyone knows how to use them, and what they should do. Testing them becomes easier as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is NORMAL in PHP for a function to return more than one type. strpos is an example. It returns an integer or a Boolean. You have to be prepared to tell the difference between integer zero or Boolean false.